# Add more packages before build

Tags: build, package, yocto, bitbake, bsp

I want to add some packages like "yasm", "glib2", "build-essential",... to my yocto distribution but don't know how to handle it.
I already enabled the "tools-sdk" in the local.conf but I need a bit more packages for my use.

Is there a way to declare other packages/images in the local.conf before running bitbake or do I have to install them later on the board?

Maybe one more question concerning the manual installation on the board:
I tried to compile and install yasm manually on the board by downloading the package and configure it. But it does give me an error cause of missing build type. I have to specify it. How do I deal with that?

I hope you understand my questions. 
Thanks for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

To add the packages to your image, specify in local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " yasm glib2 build-essential"
```

> I tried to compile and install yasm manually
>
> missing build type error

I'm not sure which error have you gotten, probably something yasm-specific. But I believe you are trying to compile yasm without specifying target architecture. Even if you don't know how to include yasm into the image, you still can compile it via `bitbake yasm`, and bitbake will handle all the parameters you need. Then you can find the artefacts in "build/tmp/work/.../yasm/.../packages-split/yasm/".